# Join Data Explode on Spark Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, databricks

I have data similar like

```
FieldA    FieldB    ExplodedField
1         A         1
1         A         2
1         A         3
2         B         3
2         B         5
```

I would like to join the data so the output will look in the following way:

```
FieldA    FieldB    ExplodedField
1         A         1
1         A         1,2
1         A         1,2,3
2         B         3
2         B         3,5
```

How would you implement it in Spark. Notice that the input dataset is very large

Answer (score 0):

Try with window **`partitionBy + orderBy`** with **`collect_list and concat_ws`** functions.

**`Example:`**

```
val df=Seq((1,"A",1),(1,"A",2),(1,"A",3)).toDF("FieldA","FieldB","ExplodedField").withColumn("mid",monotonically)

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._

val win=Window.partitionBy("FieldA","FieldB").orderBy("mid")

df.withColumn("ExplodedField",concat_ws(",",collect_list(col("ExplodedField")).over(win))).
drop("mid").
show()

/*
+------+------+-------------+
|FieldA|FieldB|ExplodedField|
+------+------+-------------+
|     1|     A|            1|
|     1|     A|          1,2|
|     1|     A|        1,2,3|
+------+------+-------------+
*/
```